# Websockets in Google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket

I am trying to run a nodejs websocket (socket.io) server in google app engine.
If i understand correctly google currently doesn't fully support websockets and in order to allow websockets server in my nodejs app, i would have to use the custom runtime.

I have read somewhere that if you use the custom runtime, your app won't scale, something that is very important to me, especially because it is a nodejs app.

Is it true? Can i somehow create a load balancer on top of my app and run multiple instances, will websockets still work?

When will google start fully supporting websockets?

Thank you,
Arik

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, socker.io is installed on a Compute Engine instance and App Engine is used as a regular web frontend:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket